# Как считать value элемента? (пишет undefined)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Столкнулся с проблемой, при считывании значении элемента выводит `undefined`. Есть две кнопки которым на `onclick` стоит одна функция. В каждой кнопке есть свое `value`, но функция отказывается читать его и выводит `undefined`.
Подскажите, что я сделал не так, где ошибка?

```js
function someFunc(){
  var value = this.value
  document.write(value);
}
```

```html
<button class="btSize" onclick="someFunc()" value="minus">-</button>
<button class="btSize" onclick="someFunc()" value="plus">+</button>
```

Comment: Вы не указали никакой this при вызове someFunc, в итоге this это window, а вовсе не кнопка

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в `this`. Его можно записать в событии в HTML, и получать как параметр функции:

```js
function someFunc(e){
  var value = e.value
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<button class="btSize" onclick="someFunc(this)" value="minus">-</button>
<button class="btSize" onclick="someFunc(this)" value="plus">+</button>
```

Или... можно не заморачиваться с `onclick="..."` и сразу в скрипте всё записать:

```js
let x = document.getElementsByClassName('btSize');
for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  x[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log( this.value ); 
    /* здесь this сразу указывает на элемент, запустивший функцию 
       x[i].value — выдало бы тот же результат */
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="btSize" value="minus">-</button>
<button class="btSize" value="plus">+</button>
```

Более страшный вариант:

```js
let x = document.getElementsByClassName('btSize');
[...x].forEach( (e)=> e.addEventListener('click', ()=> console.log( e.value ) ) );
 
/* Перевод в чуть более человеческий вид:

[...document.getElementsByClassName('btSize')].forEach( 
  function(element){
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
      console.log( this.value );
    });
  }
);

*/
```

```html
<button class="btSize" value="minus">-</button>
<button class="btSize" value="plus">+</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function someFunc(element) {
  this.value = element.value;
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

```html
<button class="btSize" onclick="someFunc(this)" value="minus">-</button>
<button class="btSize" onclick="someFunc(this)" value="plus">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function someFunc(){
  var value = this.value
  document.write(value);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.btSize')[0].onclick = 
document.querySelectorAll('.btSize')[1].onclick = someFunc;
```

```html
<button class="btSize" value="minus">-</button>
<button class="btSize" value="plus">+</button>
```